# Failed to normalize the argument for --secure-file-priv

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to execute a `load_file()` statement. The documentation tells me that `secure_file_priv` has to be disabled by setting it to `""` or should be set to a `path`. If not, `load_file()` will return `NULL`.

- When I edit `my.cnf` and set this variable in the `mysqld-group` to `""`, I can restart mariadb without any problems.
  -If I set this variable to a path (`secure_file_priv="/path/"`, I get the following output:

```
sudo systemctl restart mariadb.service

    Job for mariadb.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
    See "systemctl  status mariadb.service" and "journalctl  -xe" for details.

    > sudo systemctl  status mariadb.service
    mariadb.service - MariaDB 10.1 database server
       Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
       Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2017-09-12 10:50:59 CEST; 13s ago
      Process: 4815 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-upgrade (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 5306 ExecStart=/usr/libexec/mysqld --basedir=/usr $MYSQLD_OPTS $_WSREP_NEW_CLUSTER (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
      Process: 5271 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-prepare-db-dir mariadb.service (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
      Process: 5249 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mysql-check-socket (code=exited,         status=0/SUCCESS)
     Main PID: 5306 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
       Status: "MariaDB server is down"
    
    sep 12 10:50:57 BEL002.HOME systemd[1]: Starting MariaDB 10.1 database server...
    sep 12 10:50:58 BEL002.HOME mysql-prepare-db-dir[5271]: Database MariaDB is probably initialized in /var/lib/mysql already, nothing is done.
    sep 12 10:50:59 BEL002.HOME mysqld[5306]: 2017-09-12 10:50:59 139800931358976 [Warning] Failed to normalize the argument for --secure-file-priv.
    sep 12 10:50:59 BEL002.HOME mysqld[5306]: 2017-09-12 10:50:59 139800931358976 [ERROR] Aborting
    sep 12 10:50:59 BEL002.HOME systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    sep 12 10:50:59 BEL002.HOME systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB 10.1 database server.
    sep 12 10:50:59 BEL002.HOME systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Unit entered failed state.
    sep 12 10:50:59 BEL002.HOME systemd[1]: mariadb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I have executed `chmod 777 /path/`.

If I set `secure_file_priv` to `""`, select `load_file("file name")` still returns `NULL`.

How can I disable `secure_file_priv`?

Comment: Try: `SELECT LOAD_FILE("/path/file.name");`.

Answer (score 4):

This could happen because of systemd protection. For me, on Debian 10 buster, I had similar problem:

if `secure-file-priv=/home` - daemon starts, but fails when `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`. If `secure-file-priv=/home/username` - daemon fails to start with `Failed to normalize the argument for --secure-file-priv` error. But if I use other path for secure-file-priv, everything works well, only /home directory was 'special'.

Easy fix: edit mariadb systemd service file (for debian this is `/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service`). Find code:

```
# Prevent accessing /home, /root and /run/user
ProtectHome=true
```

and set `ProtectHome=false`.

If you have problems with other directories (`/usr`, `/boot`, `/etc`), check `ProtectSystem` option. And if problem with `/tmp` - check `PrivateTmp`.

Documentation: https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html

Comment: I have the same problem with a dir in /var, any idea ?

Comment: Even after setting ProtectHome=true , I still got this error. I had MariaDB 10.6.7-MariaDB on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS.

Answer (score 3):

I use OpenSuSe LEAP 42.3

I changed in the `/etc/my.cnf.d/secure_file_priv.cnf`
from

`secure_file_priv = /var/lib/mysql-files`

to

`secure_file_priv = /var/lib/mysql`

The folder `/var/lib/mysql-files` not exists, this is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but it worked in Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, MariaDB: 10.6.7-MariaDB).

1. Create a folder on the top level directory i.e. `/`

   ```
   sudo mkdir mysql
   ```
2. change is permission to `0777`

   ```
   sudo chmod 0777 mysql
   ```
3. Change it ownership to `mysql`

   ```
   sudo chown mysql:mysql mysql
   ```
4. Change the permission in `.cnf` file

   ```
   sudo gedit /etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
   ```
5. Add the line in `[mysqld]` section

   ```
   secure-file-priv = /mysql
   ```
6. Restart the mysql service

   ```
   sudo systemctl restart mysql.service
   ```
7. Export the table to csv file

   ```
   SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/mysql/fileName.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' FROM tableName;
   ```

That's it; you had successfully exported your table to a csv file.